# How is this broad, unclear, for-recommendation-asking question good and upvoted?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Could somebody please enlighten me, why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15770385/4792869) is not closed and even often upvoted?

For me, several close reasons apply:

- Too broad
- Unclear what you're asking
- Asking to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource
- Maybe even opinion-based

Comment: Lots of people really enjoy discussing extremely broad questions, providing their recommendations, expressing their opinions, etc.  The fact that people love to do it (despite the fact that such questions aren't actually useful) is precisely why we want these types of questions closed.  Of course, it's also why they so often don't get closed despite the fact that they should be.

Comment: The question is closed now.

Comment: *Why is this question not closed* because we have a backlog of stuff to close and there aren't enough of us to keep that queue in the low numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up: the question **is** off-topic, but was loved by people who enjoy discussing a subject on Stack Overflow.

It is now closed.